# Insert a string between each array of objects with a specific string for last tag

Tags: javascript

I need to display a list of names with commas and the word "and" for last tag (*eg: John, Stan, Kevin, Jane and Laura*). Actually, I create a function, but I would like to improve it. Thank you in advance for your response.

```js
var tab = [
 {
  name: "John"
 },{
  name: "Stan"
 },{
  name: "Kevin"
 },{
  name: "Jane"
 },{
  name: "Laura"
 }
];

tab = tab.map(function(e) { return e.name });
tab = tab.join(', ');
tabIndex = tab.lastIndexOf(',');
tab = tab.substring(0, tabIndex) + " and" + tab.substring(tabIndex + 1 );

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = tab;
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: use `slice(0,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify by using a regular expression:

```
tab = tab.map(function(e) { return e.name })
         .join(', ')
         .replace(/, ([^,]+)$/, ' and $1');
```

`/, ([^,]+)$/` matches the last comma followed by a name.

Here is how it works:

- `[^,]+` matches multiple characters having no comma.
- `$` matches the end of text.
- The parentheses around `([^,]+)` make the last name a grouping, which is substituted for `$1` in the replaced string.

Using this regular expression, the last name can contain spaces or other characters, as demonstrated in the Snippet.

**Snippet:**

```js
var tab = [
 {
  name: "John"
 },{
  name: "Stan"
 },{
  name: "Kevin"
 },{
  name: "Jane"
 },{
  name: "Laura May"
 }
];

tab = tab.map(function(e) { return e.name })
         .join(', ')
         .replace(/, ([^,]+)$/, ' and $1');

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = tab;
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and do as following

check this snippet

```js
var tab = [{
  name: "John"
}, {
  name: "Stan"
}, {
  name: "Kevin"
}, {
  name: "Jane"
}, {
  name: "Laura"
}];
var namesarr = tab.reduce(function(names, obj) {
  names.push(obj.name);
  return names;
}, []);

var remArray = namesarr.splice(4);

remArray.unshift("and");

var remString = remArray.join(" ");

console.log(namesarr.join(",").concat(" ").concat(remString));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Why use `reduce` when OP's `map` works just as well with less code?